# BING default search enginge Firefox malware?

Tags: malware, firefox

Whenever I open Firefox, it starts with the BING search engine. The default search enginge of Firefox was set to "MyFireSearch" which I changed to Google. I also have no extensions that change the default search machine. The OS is Windows 10. However, when I reboot, the default search enginge that pops up is still BING,

I have downloaded Malwarebytes and it found something called "PUP.Optional.MyFireSearch". I removed the 18 foundings, and rebooted my PC; but still BING is open up first.

Any suggestions why BING happens to be the default search enginge on Firefox despite default SE is set to Google?

Here is the full log of MalwareBytes:

```
Malwarebytes
www.malwarebytes.com

-Protokolldetails-
Scan-Datum: 15.08.21
Scan-Zeit: 14:55
Protokolldatei: 0f3f90b8-fdc8-11eb-b211-1002b5a8c6b2.json

-Softwaredaten-
Version: 4.4.4.126
Komponentenversion: 1.0.1413
Version des Aktualisierungspakets: 1.0.44164
Lizenz: Testversion

-Systemdaten-
Betriebssystem: Windows 10 (Build 19043.1110)
CPU: x64
Dateisystem: NTFS
Benutzer: DESKTOP-Q463N52\nandana

-Scan-Übersicht-
Scan-Typ: Bedrohungs-Scan
Scan gestartet von: Manuell
Ergebnis: Abgeschlossen
Gescannte Objekte: 398192
Erkannte Bedrohungen: 20
In die Quarantäne verschobene Bedrohungen: 0
Abgelaufene Zeit: 9 Min., 48 Sek.

-Scan-Optionen-
Speicher: Aktiviert
Start: Aktiviert
Dateisystem: Aktiviert
Archive: Aktiviert
Rootkits: Deaktiviert
Heuristik: Aktiviert
PUP: Erkennung
PUM: Erkennung

-Scan-Details-
Prozess: 0
(keine bösartigen Elemente erkannt)

Modul: 0
(keine bösartigen Elemente erkannt)

Registrierungsschlüssel: 3
PUP.Optional.Conduit, HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\SEARCHSCOPES\{0633EE93-D776-472F-A0FF-E1416B8B2E3A}, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 193, 236865, , , , , , 
PUP.Optional.Conduit, HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\SEARCHSCOPES\{0633EE93-D776-472F-A0FF-E1416B8B2E3A}, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 193, 236865, , , , , , 
PUP.Optional.Conduit, HKU\S-1-5-21-2685318252-1365662529-2013666176-1001\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\SEARCHSCOPES\{0633EE93-D776-472f-A0FF-E1416B8B2E3A}, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 193, 236865, 1.0.44164, , ame, , , 

Registrierungswert: 2
PUP.Optional.Conduit, HKU\S-1-5-21-2685318252-1365662529-2013666176-1001\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\SEARCHSCOPES\{0633EE93-D776-472f-A0FF-E1416B8B2E3A}|URL, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 193, 236865, 1.0.44164, , ame, , , 
PUP.Optional.Conduit, HKU\S-1-5-21-2685318252-1365662529-2013666176-1001\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\SEARCHSCOPES\{0633EE93-D776-472f-A0FF-E1416B8B2E3A}|TOPRESULTURL, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 193, 236865, 1.0.44164, , ame, , , 

Registrierungsdaten: 1
PUP.Optional.Conduit, HKU\S-1-5-21-2685318252-1365662529-2013666176-1001\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\MAIN|START PAGE, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 193, 293058, 1.0.44164, , ame, , , 

Daten-Stream: 0
(keine bösartigen Elemente erkannt)

Ordner: 1
PUP.Optional.MindSpark.Generic, C:\USERS\NANDANA\APPDATA\ROAMING\MOZILLA\FIREFOX\PROFILES\407VDGSR.DEFAULT\BROWSER-EXTENSION-DATA\_39Members_@www.mapsgalaxy.com, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 1893, 782572, 1.0.44164, , ame, , , 

Datei: 13
PUP.Optional.RemoteInjectionFF.Generic, C:\USERS\NANDANA\APPDATA\ROAMING\MOZILLA\FIREFOX\PROFILES\407VDGSR.DEFAULT\EXTENSIONS\extension@plgdehoverwikde.xpi, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 4708, 694112, 1.0.44164, , ame, , 4A27783BDFB3A5F284B7692D77E01EB6, 41B9D43C2B612246FEEADC28FB7B6907D6AB36198622B1FDB9B86BBAAD05A23E
PUP.Optional.Spigot.Generic, C:\USERS\NANDANA\APPDATA\ROAMING\MOZILLA\FIREFOX\PROFILES\407VDGSR.DEFAULT\EXTENSIONS\web@fd9b3d8a-1178-45ab-92a8-a172d0b7c32e.xpi, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 199, 662624, 1.0.44164, , ame, , CBA63333B8EBD5C16A687C43EA60E018, 5BFDD457F0B267242B433E1A06A02DCA2800CCA5D1E54428BFA5F621DD758F25
PUP.Optional.MindSpark.Generic, C:\USERS\NANDANA\APPDATA\ROAMING\MOZILLA\FIREFOX\PROFILES\U66EISZ2.DEFAULT-1554915626842\EXTENSIONS\_l6Members_@www.propdfconverter.com.xpi, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 1893, 782571, 1.0.44164, , ame, , ADDB343024AFEA190EB4CD7BBB858C83, 93C406852C08C04709DF1E4C865225C4E0D546098FAD4F5396734076C455EE42
PUP.Optional.MindSpark.Generic, C:\Users\nandana\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\407vdgsr.default\browser-extension-data\_39Members_@www.mapsgalaxy.com\storage.js, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 1893, 782572, , , , , 3D3208F1163789879F7C3C506191B3E6, 1CAD6EC44ABF3CA8955BD03BD230D29A87DCE3A2C8FE1B902DDF9DA27D39A7BF
PUP.Optional.MyFireSearch, C:\USERS\NANDANA\APPDATA\ROAMING\MOZILLA\FIREFOX\PROFILES\U66EISZ2.DEFAULT-1554915626842\PREFS.JS, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 380, 914864, 1.0.44164, , ame, , DC2ED0D63168E3C117DCBCEF6D5E85C7, 972669E22C556DF4404A6399F278D5785899E19F9FF810777C86C513CD196A5E
PUP.Optional.MyFireSearch, C:\USERS\NANDANA\APPDATA\ROAMING\MOZILLA\FIREFOX\PROFILES\U66EISZ2.DEFAULT-1554915626842\PREFS.JS, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 380, 914865, 1.0.44164, , ame, , DC2ED0D63168E3C117DCBCEF6D5E85C7, 972669E22C556DF4404A6399F278D5785899E19F9FF810777C86C513CD196A5E
PUP.Optional.MyFireSearch, C:\USERS\NANDANA\APPDATA\ROAMING\MOZILLA\FIREFOX\PROFILES\U66EISZ2.DEFAULT-1554915626842\PREFS.JS, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 380, 914866, 1.0.44164, , ame, , DC2ED0D63168E3C117DCBCEF6D5E85C7, 972669E22C556DF4404A6399F278D5785899E19F9FF810777C86C513CD196A5E
PUP.Optional.MyFireSearch, C:\USERS\NANDANA\APPDATA\ROAMING\MOZILLA\FIREFOX\PROFILES\U66EISZ2.DEFAULT-1554915626842\PREFS.JS, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 380, 914867, 1.0.44164, , ame, , DC2ED0D63168E3C117DCBCEF6D5E85C7, 972669E22C556DF4404A6399F278D5785899E19F9FF810777C86C513CD196A5E
PUP.Optional.MyFireSearch, C:\USERS\NANDANA\APPDATA\ROAMING\MOZILLA\FIREFOX\PROFILES\U66EISZ2.DEFAULT-1554915626842\PREFS.JS, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 380, 914868, 1.0.44164, , ame, , DC2ED0D63168E3C117DCBCEF6D5E85C7, 972669E22C556DF4404A6399F278D5785899E19F9FF810777C86C513CD196A5E
PUP.Optional.MyFireSearch, C:\USERS\NANDANA\APPDATA\ROAMING\MOZILLA\FIREFOX\PROFILES\U66EISZ2.DEFAULT-1554915626842\SEARCHPLUGINS\MY FIREFOX SEARCH.XML, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 380, 910806, 1.0.44164, , ame, , 7B553DD3EF7F364986BAB4F7CC32723E, 0CE41BB8F69106A56B0BCB2C462680105C2D438BADD088E4D3810F389B0717FB
PUP.Optional.ChipDe, C:\USERS\NANDANA\DOWNLOADS\DEEPL111SETUP - CHIP-INSTALLER.EXE, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 634, 562568, 1.0.44164, 303692B75E5530EDEBD83394, dds, 01378684, 715968E77A6BD375A39B6275832D9F87, 9C3679D80807B4259D142AB33CDFE30DBD704EDD7E9B2086DC2636E964A1BAF9
PUP.Optional.ChipDe, C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-2685318252-1365662529-2013666176-1001\$R6W7TSD.EXE, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 634, 621518, 1.0.44164, , ame, , 2A4349E966D67A75792DD6B2E4AD1123, 2C30B99A54AA71AE801B2BC672EDA7AF8039F50AECDE55F30F2D89DF99FF97DA
PUP.Optional.ChipDe, C:\WINDOWS\INSTALLER\1B6A9BB7.MSI, Keine Aktion durch Benutzer, 634, 557991, 1.0.44164, , ame, , DD85FF75F142CFA6B7DD7955DC5914F0, C26A8FF8AD1FC72873EB7C975214D9DD0CD5EE8AFD663E662136677ADB5579FE

Physischer Sektor: 0
(keine bösartigen Elemente erkannt)

WMI: 0
(keine bösartigen Elemente erkannt)


(end)
```

Comment: And when you run Malwarebytes again, does it come back clean?

Comment: *"I also have no extensions that change the default search machine."* -  The logged PUP.Optional.MyFireSearch sounds exactly like such an extension though.

Comment: Maybe you have to remove the malware and then set your search engine back to how you want it.